Access queue to a shared resource
The following simple interface aims at giving access to a C++ third party api from a shell:
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "thirdparty_api.hpp"
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::cout << thirdparty_run(argv[1]) << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

After compiling that function in an executable named tpapi_run, it is possible to call this command from a shell like that:
> tpapi_run a
some result
> tpapi_run b
another result

I want now to be able to call this command tpapi_run from several different parallel processes, however the thirdparty resource can't handle several series of call in parallel as its state must be reinitialized for each new process (otherwise the results will be corrupted). This means, the first process calling tpapi_run should monopolize the api and force the others to wait in a queue until it calls another command, let say tpapi_release which will release the resource and allow the next process to perform its calls. The following example illustrate the sequence between three processes:
process_1: tpapi_run a   > process_1 receives result corresponding to a
process_2: tpapi_run b   > process_2 is waiting
process_3: tpapi_run c   > process_3 is waiting
process_1: tpapi_run b   > process_1 receives result corresponding to b
...
process_1: tpapi_release > process_2 receives result corresponding to b
process_2: tpapi_run a   > process_2 receives result corresponding to a
...
process_2: tpapi_release > process 3 receives result corresponding to c

Is there a C++ library or method to achieve this goal ?

what about automating this with python ? this is like 10-20 lines of python code for all your requirements, including the timeout, you don't need to create artificial complexity, python is mostly the best language for monitoring and automating a bunch of processes, i'd even bet something like chatgpt will give you the code if you ask it nicely.

Why not, thanks. I will investigate this idea. My constraint is anyway that my api is in cpp and I must be able to call it from different parallel shells (So each process doesn't know the other processes calling in parallel). I will check how Python could help for that.

now that you put your requirements this way, you won't be able to do that in python, you'd rather have to go the long way of implementing that stuff in C++ ...

@AhmedAEK: You can easily call into C++ via an extension (we’re already writing C++ here) or in some cases an FFI (ctypes).

Take a look at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tsp.1.html
